# Create a Loading page between two PHP pages

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have two PHP pages...page A and page B. Page A is basically a form that takes input values from a user and posts them to page B which runs a python script to do some calculations over the submitted values and presents the calculated values on page B. I want to include a page C in between A and B which displays a loading bar or icon meanwhile the page B's content is prepared to be displayed, and then directs user to the page B. Is there a pure PHP or PHP+JS+CSS way of doing this?

The idea is to capture the status of page B and the user is only directed to Page B from Page C when Page B's content is ready to be displayed.

Comment: i would do a to b, b uses ajax to call the process code, and shows loading graphic, then displays data when ready

Comment: Yeah, that right, you need to use ajax

Comment: I am not good with ajax..if you can give me any hints or tips this may be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to do something like this.

Both begin with AJAX; when you submit A.php it should send an AJAX request instead of loading B.php directly. A then has a chance to act on the response as it happens.

For communicating progress, here are your options:

1. B.php prints to the output at regular intervals. This is easy, and used to be used in a few places for reporting file compression progress among other things. It isn't very reliable. Buffering means it will jump around and generally behave badly. This doesn't *need* AJAX, but will look ugly without it.
2. B.php writes to a file at regular intervals, and D.php reads this file and returns the results. Now you make A.php send a request to D.php every couple of seconds (or whatever you need for good results) with a query parameter saying which request to check the progress of. This is much more reliable, but harder to set up.

Comment: I have no idea about how to use AJAX on these pages..any tutorial or sample that you can recommend?

Comment: I strongly recommend you use a library for it. jQuery is my favourite (it does a lot of fancy javascript stuff), and this is the relevant documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/